# Programmatically making a GET request

Tags: c#, jquery

Say I had the following Jquery request

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8501/exampleservice.svc/rest/Start",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            data: { confirmationNum : '90210' },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, xhr)
            {
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status)
            {
            }
        });
```

What is the proper way to this correctly in C#? 
I have tried the following with an error occurring at the data stream:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' "

```
string biometricURL = "http://localhost:8501/exampleservice.svc/rest/Start";
byte[] jsonData = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("{ confirmationNum : '90210' }");
WebRequest request;
request = WebRequest.Create(biometricURL);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(jsonData, 0, jsonData.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)getBiometricCapture.GetResponse();
```

Comment: you don't need to set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` if you have already specify `dataType: "json"`

Comment: did you check if the Method is GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included the data as part of the URL like this.

```
HttpWebRequest request =   (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8501/exampleservice.svc/rest/Start?confirmationNum='90210'");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

The matter here is that you have a body in your GET request. Here are two solutions to solve your issue:

1. Change your request type to `POST` instead of `GET` (`type: "POST"`)
2. Remove your  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` parameter. `ContentType` is useless if you're doing a `GET` request. `GET` requests should not have content-type because they do not have request entity.

Answer (score 2):

The GET Request does not have a body / content. As a result, using the:

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(jsonData, 0, jsonData.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

may cause the "System.Net.ProtocolViolationException".

If you want to pass custom data through the GET Request, append custom parameters via the QueryString or Headers.

Otherwise, use the POST Request instead.

Answer (score 1):

As other users have already answered, you don't pass JSON objects in the content body for a GET request.  However, using a post method like they suggest is not RESTful, which is what it appears you are trying to build based on the semantics of your example URL.

In RESTful services, simple accessors are implemented with the parameters passed as URL path fragments (the exception generally being complicated queries, in which case you use query variables in the URL or a POST).  This is not the case for you, as you are accessing by a simple ID.  So, for example, if you are trying to get a BiometricCapture resource with id 12345, you would access the URL:

`http://localhost:8501/exampleservice.svc/rest/biocaptures/12345`